# How to Update App to (native?) Material design

Tags: android, android-theme

I see that Google updated some apps (like Hangout) to the new Material Design.

How can I do that too?
I have a Nexus 5(Android 4.4), but if I set the Theme in the styles.xml to "android: style / Theme.Material", Android Studio reports (of course) API 21 +: Android L (Preview) needed.

How has Google done this?

Comment: The Android 20 SDK has been around for quite some time, just go to the SDK Manager and install it?

Comment: Yea Recent API is 21 now. Get the SDK and don't forget to set your target in Android Manifest to API 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use appcompat v21 - material design for pre-Lollipop devices. To use the same (if you are on android studio) Update your SDK and add appcompat as a dependency in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {  
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0"
}
```

And i guess you are ready to go code using material design for pre L devices.

You can read more about it [here](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/).